# Как сделать запрос к mySQL на выбор нескольких определенных значений?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$ip_sql=mysql_query("select ip_id from vote_ip where mes_id_fk='1' and ip_add='$ip'");
$count=mysql_fetch_array($ip_sql);
```

В общем, нужно чтобы `select` брал 10 `ip_id`,  где `mes_id_fk=`от 1 до 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select ip_id from vote_ip where (mes_id_fk BETWEEN 1 AND 10) and ip_add='$ip'
```

или

```
select ip_id from vote_ip where mes_id_fk < 10 and ip_add='$ip'
```

Comment: Вот да, то что нужно! Еще если есть все 10 строк, то запрос возьмет 10 значений в массив, а если, например, 3 значений нету, массив получится из 7, а нужно, чтобы где нет значений отдавало 0.

Comment: за использование between +1 ) Не пришло в голову на момент написания ответа :).
Ну и вариант с IN() точно также работает :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ip_sql=mysql_query("select ip_id from vote_ip where mes_id_fk IN('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10') and ip_add='$ip' LIMIT 10");
$count=mysql_fetch_array($ip_sql);
```

Comment: Не подходит sql запрос вам?

Comment: Array ( [0] => 1 [ip_id] => 1 ) получается не массивит))

Answer (score 0):

Что-то с трудом понял вопрос, но! В запросе mysql_query дописать такие вещи как `ORDER BY` и `LIMIT`.
Вывод данных осуществлять через цикл:

```
while($count=mysql_fetch_array($ip_sql)) {
  echo $count['И нужное поле из бд'];
}
```

P.S. Или я плохо понял)

Comment: Нужно выбрать 10 значений, где у всех одинаковый `IP(ip_add)`, но разное `mes_id_fk`. Причем `mes_id_fk` строго определены. В общем, это нужно для голосовалки, чтобы знать, отвечал ли юзер на даннный вопрос.